How to show BootstrapTable headers and sub headers?
I am working with React Js for Frontend application. I have one table structure like below-
                                                        <BootstrapTable
                                                            classes="table"                                                                 
                                                            data={
                                                                this.props.School
                                                            }                                                               
                                                            columns={[
                                                                {
                                                                    dataField: 'Id',
                                                                    text: 'ID'                                                                      
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    dataField: 'firstName',
                                                                    text: 'First Name',
                                                                    sort: false,                                                                        
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    dataField: 'lastName',
                                                                    text: 'Last Name',
                                                                    sort: false
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    dataField: 'rollNo',
                                                                    text: 'Roll Number',
                                                                    sort: false                                                                 
                                                                },
                                                            ]}
                                                        />

And the table is showing like below-

But I have new requirement to show table structure (headers + sub-headers) like below-


You can take this simple approach:
import React from 'react'

export default function yourReactFunctionalComponent() {
    const columns = [
        {
            dataField: 'Id',
            text: 'ID'
        },
        {
            dataField: 'firstName',
            text: 'First Name',
            sort: false,
        },
        {
            dataField: 'lastName',
            text: 'Last Name',
            sort: false
        },
        {
            dataField: 'rollNo',
            text: 'Roll Number',
            sort: false
        }
    ];
    return (
        <>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Part I</th>
                        <th>Part II</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <BootstrapTable classes = "table" data = {this.props.School} columns = {columns}/>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </>
    )
}


To fulfill your requirement, for showing headers + sub-headers, you can refer to the below react code snippet:
        import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
        import React from 'react';

        // Example data
        const data = [
            { Id: 1, firstName: 'Sunil', lastName: 'Kumar', rollNo: 101 },
            { Id: 2, firstName: 'Amit', lastName: 'Jain', rollNo: 102 }
        ];

        // Custom table header
        const CustomTableHeader = () => (
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colSpan="2" style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Part I</th>
                    <th colSpan="2" style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightblue', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Part II</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgreen', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>ID</th>
                    <th style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgreen', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>First Name</th>
                    <th style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgreen', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Last Name</th>
                    <th style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgreen', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Roll Number</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        );

        const CustomTable = () => {
            const columns = [
                { dataField: 'Id', text: 'ID' },
                { dataField: 'firstName', text: 'First Name' },
                { dataField: 'lastName', text: 'Last Name' },
                { dataField: 'rollNo', text: 'Roll Number' }
            ];

            return (
                <BootstrapTable
                    keyField="Id"
                    data={data}
                    columns={columns}
                    headerClasses="custom-header"
                    classes="table"
                    headerWrapper={CustomTableHeader}
                />
            );
        };

        export default CustomTable;


Both Tables are same, output table & desired output table is same, give some breif

updated the screen shot.
